# python prompt available whilst outputting data

Tags: python, console

I'm fairly new to python and need help with the following.

Say I have some code which is continually outputting data to the Python console, e.g.:

```
for x in range(10000): print x
```

I then want to be able to enter various commands which may affect the output immediately. For example, I enter a number which causes the loop to start again from this number, or I enter step=2, which causes the step level to change, etc.

Basically, I want the code to run and print in the background, while the prompt is still available.

Is such a thing possible? I'm guessing the output would have to be sent to a new window, but I am unsure how this would work out in practice. I would prefer no GUI at the moment, as I just want to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: start a background thread, and communicate with it trough your input prompt/console

Answer (score 0):

As @BlueRhine S says start a background thread. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html) is a link to the standard library threading module docs. I would probably prefer to start a sub-process though and use a pipe to communicate between your foreground process and the worker process. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is a link to those docs